# eclim autoimport removing current line

Tags: vim, youcompleteme, eclim

Eclim by default automagically imports java classes when they aren't imported yet. It used to do this successfully, but now the import happens and the line I am currently editing gets deleted.

My hypothesis is that there is some conflicting plugin running at the same time. Whats a good way to figure that out? I tried looking at vim verbose output (via verbosefile) but I am not sure what to look for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was just fixed in the source code, you could try patching in this change and rebuilding eclim from source (or waiting for the next release):

https://github.com/ervandew/eclim/pull/529